# Glyphicons - won't load locally using IE 10; CDN will load

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a really weird problem.  I cannot load the Glyphicons using IE 10 if I load Bootstrap 3.3.5 from the server, but I can load Glyphicons if I use the CDN.

I do not have this problem with FireFox or Chrome.

I checked the Font Download feature in IE and it is enabled.  It is not a problem with IIS because I can download the icons using FireFox and Chrome and the mimetypes are added to the mimetypes section of IIS.

The files are in the appropriate directory relative to Bootstraps CSS files.

Additionally, using Fiddler, I'm getting a status of 200 for downloading the files.  The only thing of note is that when I try to display the page and it's loads the CSS on the local server, it appears that it's trying to download all of the font files, but when I load the page using bootstrap.min.css from the CDN, it only downloads the eot file.

Does anyone have any additional advice on how to resolve this?  I would prefer to load the files locally rather than over the CDN.

Edit - Based on the following comment:

```
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
```

Folder structure:

```
+-AppFolder
|----Css
|----Fonts
```

Comment: You should post your CSS for loading the fonts locally. How do you expect people to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the HTTP Response Headers, specifically Pragma: no-cache.

Removing Pragma: no-cache caused the fonts to display properly.  Cache-control: no-cache and Expires: 0 have no effect on the display of the icons.